# Find items that are similar amongst them in List in C# with nested For loops and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, loops, for-loop, nested

I have the below code working fine, which finds items which are similar amongst each other within the list by ± 2. I would like to have 2 versions to check which one runs faster.

**Version a)** is with nested For Loops, as the code below. However the last part of the code has a !List.Contains() which I would like it to be replaced by another For loop as the Contains() adds 4500 ticks, whereas the other 2 nested for loops only take 1500 ticks. So I would appreciate if someone can help replace the Contains() with another for loop and deliver the same result.

**Version b)** the same but with LINQ.

**In both versions the items within the output List intTestResult must be: (1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 12)**

```
        int intOffset = 2;
        List<int> intTest = new List<int> { 1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 19, 24 };
        List<int> intTestResult = new List<int>();

        var S1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int a = 0; a < intTest.Count; a++)

            {
                int int1 = intTest[a];

                for (int b = 0; b < intTest.Count; b++)

                {

                int int2 = intTest[b];

                if (int1 + intOffset >= int2 && int1 - intOffset <= int2 && int1 != int2)


                    {

                    if (!intTestResult.Contains(int1))                      

                        intTestResult.Add(int1);

                    }
                }
            }

        S1.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Ticks = " + S1.ElapsedTicks);
```

/* Ticks elapsed 6000

intTestResult items are (1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 12) */

Comment: You need to show us the LINQ version if you want us to look at it.

Comment: `if (Math.Abs(int1 - int2) <= 2)` is simpler.

Comment: @Jim Mischel  `if (Math.Abs(int1 - int2) <= intOffset && int1 != int2)` is simpler but also 1500 ticks slower.

Comment: How big array of integers you are testing with?

Comment: @Fabio the list is small 20 items.

Comment: @Roblogic, for 20 items you don't need to worry about performance - write code which will be easy/fast to process for your colleague's brain (readable code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
if (!intTestResult.Contains(int1))                      
    intTestResult.Add(int1);
```

with

```
bool contains = false;
for(int c = 0; c < intTestResult.Count; c++)
{
    if(int1 == intTestResult[c])
    {
        contains = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!contains)
    intTestResult.Add(int1);
```

Comment: Thanks very much!. It does all the calculations in around 1500 ticks. Much faster than with the List.Contains()

Answer (score 1):

Afraid the way you measure effectiveness is wrong.

1. First you should execute method multiple times, in the loop for example. Because first execution will always take more time and probably you can exclude first loop from the calculation.
2. Use big amount of data to process. Many effective data structures are slow with small data, but very quick with big amount of data.
3. If your application doesn't work with big amount of data, then you don't need to test performance at all. **Just write the code which will be easy to read and understand for other developers(yourself)**. I would say "Write code which can be quickly processed by human brain".

Approach with `HashSet<int>` and `Enumerable.Aggregate`

```
// Helper method to check if two numbers within offset
private IEnumerable<int> WithinOffset(int? previous, int current, int offset)
{
    if (previous.HasValue == false)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    var difference = Math.Abs(previous.Value, current);
    if (difference > 0 && difference <= offset)
    {
        yield return previous.Value;
        yield return current;
    }
}

var clock = Stopwatch.Start();

var offset = 2;
var result = 
    givenData.OrderBy(number => number)
             .Aggregate(
                 (All: Enumerable.Empty<int>(), Last: default(int?)),
                 (summary, current) => 
                 {
                     var withinOffset = WithinOffset(summery.Last, current, offset);
                     var all = summary.All.Concat(withinOffset);
                     return (all, current);
                 },
                 (summary) => summary.All.ToHashSet().ToList());
clock.Stop();

var ticks = clock.ElapsedTicks;
```

If I follow your approach to measure, but will provide list with 1000 items

```
var template = new[] { 1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 19, 24 }
var givenData = 
    Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
              .Select(i => i * 100)
              .Select(i => template.Select(number => number + i))
              .SelectMany(number => number)
              .ToList();


// Approach with accepted answer
// Elapsed ticks = 11517000 (1.1517 seconds)

// Approach with HashSet, OrderBy and Aggregate
// Elapsed ticks = 2202000 (0.2202 seconds)
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try this but it was slightly slower than !List.Contains(). It was taking around 8000 ticks.

Comment: @Roblogic, HashSet is much faster for bigger amount of data. Check updated answer